# Flexbox - different items order on mobile than on desktop

Tags: responsive-design, flexbox

I’m trying to do a responsive website in `flexbox`.

This is how my website looks like on [big screens](http://wstaw.org/m/2016/02/21/bigscreen.png).

And this is what I want to get on [mobile devices](http://wstaw.org/m/2016/02/21/smallscreen.png).

As you can see, my problem lies in the different order of items on mobile and on the desktop.

My question is: is it possible to do?

Comment: *I’m trying to do* What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best layout I can think of right now: traditional float for big screen & flex for small screen to reorder.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box !important; }
    [class^="item-"] {
      background-color: blue;
      border: 3px solid white;
      color: white;
      float: left;
    }

    .item-1, .item-5, .item-6, .item-9 {
      float: none;
    }

    .item-2 {
      width: 33.33%;
      height: 300px;
    }

    .item-3, .item-4 {
      width: 33.33%;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .item-5 {
      height: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .item-7, .item-8 {
      width: 50%;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      [class^="item-"] {
        float: none;
        width: initial;
        height: 50px;
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .item-5 {
        order: 1;
      }

      .item-2 {
        order: 2;
      }

      .item-6 {
        order: 3;
      }

      .item-7 {
        order: 4;
      }

      .item-8 {
        order: 5;
      }

      .item-9 {
        order: 6;
      }

      .item-3 {
        order: 7;
      }

      .item-4 {
        order: 8;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1">item1</div>
  <div class="item-2">item2</div>
  <div class="item-3">item3</div>
  <div class="item-4">item4</div>
  <div class="item-5">item5</div>
  <div class="item-6">item6</div>
  <div class="item-7">item7</div>
  <div class="item-8">item8</div>
  <div class="item-9">item9</div>
</div>
```